# Get message type from PipeContext from MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am implementing a MassTransit middleware in my receive end point to record the performance of handling the message, i want to get the message type from the PipeContext, how can i get it?

```
public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        // I want to know the message type from here so that i can log it
        using (_logger.BeginTimedOperation("Time for handling message", null, LogEventLevel.Debug))
        {
            await next.Send(context);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to intercept at the `ConsumeContext`, which has a property for the message types from the serialization envelope.

Then, you can get the supported message types using:

```
IEnumerable<string> SupportedMessageTypes {get;}
```

That should get you what you need to log the message type with the duration.

So a filter along the lines of:

```
public class LogMessageTypeFilter :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext>
{
}
```

Implement the send method, call next within the method, and then take action after the next pipe completes.